# Initialization of variable 'variableName' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

Tags: swift

I only have a couple of warning msgs remaining in my app. I've borrowed some code and this happens to be the area with the warning msgs. App runs fine, no issues but I'd like to find out why those warning msgs are there.

The same warning msgs appear in two separate swift files because they're using similar code.

WriteViewController.swift

*Initialization of variable 'memoNum' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
Initialization of variable 'i' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it*

```
@IBAction func save(){

    /*----------------------------------------*/
    var memoNum = memo.count  // <—- error 
    var i: Int = 0            // <—- error 

    print(memo)

    let id:AnyObject = convertUnixTimeFromDate(NSDate())
    let newDic = ["id":id,"contents":writeView.text]

    print("newDic=\(newDic)¥¥¥")
    print(memo)
    print(memoArray)

    let memoDictionary = ["id":id,"contents":writeView.text]


    var tempArr : Array = memoArray as Array
    print("beforeReverse=\(tempArr)")
    var tempArr2 = Array(tempArr.reverse()) 
    print("afterReverse=\(tempArr2)")
    var tArray : NSArray = tempArr2 as NSArray
    memoArray = tArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

    memoArray.addObject(memoDictionary)

    tempArr  = memoArray as Array
    print("beforeReverse=\(tempArr)")
     tempArr2 = tempArr.reverse()
    print("afterReverse=\(tempArr2)")
    tArray  = tempArr2 as NSArray
    memoArray = tArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray


    /*--------------------------------------------------*/

    UD.setObject(memoArray, forKey: "array")   
    print(memo)
    UD.synchronize()   

    writeView.text=""
    self.view.endEditing(true)   
    writeView.resignFirstResponder()

    let alert2 = UIAlertController()
    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

EditViewController.swift

*Initialization of variable 'TD' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
Initialization of variable 'TDArray' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it*

```
@IBAction func edit(){
    var i: Int



    print(memo)



    if(searchString == ""){
        var dic  = memo[cellNum] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

        print("dic=\(dic)")
        dic["contents"] = editView.text as String

        memo[cellNum]=dic
        memoArray[cellNum]=memo[cellNum]!
    }else{
        var TD : Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject> = [:]  // <—— error
        var TDArray : NSMutableArray = []              // <—— error
        let edtTxt = editView.text as String
        var dic = tmpDictionaryArray[cellNum] as! Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>
        dic["contents"] = edtTxt

        tmpDictionaryArray[cellNum]=dic

        let tmpId: Double = dic["id"] as! Double

        print("memo=\(memo)")

        for(var k=0;k<memo.count;k++){
            let Tmp = memo[k] as! NSDictionary
            print("Tmp=\(Tmp)")
            let double : Double = Tmp["id"] as! Double
            print("tmpId=\(tmpId)")
            print("double=\(double)")
            if(double == tmpId){

                var dic = memo[cellNum] as! Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>
                dic["contents"] = edtTxt
                memo[k] = dic
                memoArray[k]=memo[k]!
                print("Tmp=\(Tmp)")
                print("memo=\(memo)")
            }
        }
        print("tmpDA=\(tmpDictionaryArray)")

    }

    print(memo)
    UD.setObject(memoArray as NSArray, forKey: "array")   
    print(memo)
    UD.synchronize()   

    self.view.endEditing(true)   


    //Notification
    let ns = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    ns.postNotificationName(MyNotification, object: nil)

   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)   
}
```

Comment: *Initialization of variable 'memoNum' was never used*, this error seems pretty clear.

Comment: Hello there. I know what the underscore means. I do not know why I'm getting the msg since the variables are actually being used. Look at the code. When I use the underscore I get error msgs not warning msgs. I can't just delete properties that are being used. I deleted the lines and obviously got errors all over the place.

Comment: Looked over your code. It was never used. Also, don't post code like this on SO. Remove all the `print()` lines and create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We do not know what kind of object `memo` is for example. So we can not possible test the code posted.